# Returning the last date of xts object with end()

Tags: r, xts, quantmod, blotter

I am using blotter and related packages to create a small portfolio. These packages rely on data from yahoo. Additionally, they are using `xts` internally, but somehow the functions on a `xts` object don't work and return the desired results. This of course would need a lot of changing the internal features just to replace `end()` with a working call like `max(index())`.

```
library(quantmod)
library(xts)
getSymbols("LGQM.DE", from="2017-01-01", to=Sys.Date(), src='yahoo',
          auto.assign = TRUE, adjust = TRUE)

str(LGQM.DE)
end(LGQM.DE)

max(index(LGQM.DE))
```

As can be seen, when executing this code the end() function only returns an empty date value, although the date is stored properly, as can be seen when checking the result of `max(index(LGQM.DE))`.
The packages were installed from github using the `devtools` and I restarted the R session after the installation.

Comment: `end(LGQM.DE)` and `max(index(LGQM.DE))` both return the same for me: `"2018-05-24"`, that is `structure(17675, tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date", class = "Date")`

Comment: Hmm, ok then something on my system is wrong, thanks.

Comment: Don't know if it makes a difference, but I got `quantmod` etc. from CRAN and is on R 3.5.0.

Comment: Ok, just reinstalled from CRAN on R 3.5.0 and it works, sorry for the noise, will open an issue on github.

Comment: It's not clear where you intend to open an issue, and what the issue would be. I could not replicate this using the latest development xts, so I doubt the issue is with xts.

Comment: Perhaps it's in quantmod. Not sure, but I am still seeing it with versions  quantmod_0.4-13.1 and xts_0.10-2.1 installed from github.
Opened https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/238